# How can I remove the big vertical space between the window menu and its items?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

As you can see here, there is a big vertical space between the menu header and the menu items.

[image]

This time it occurred in Anki, but it has happened in LibreOffice a while ago.

1. Why does this occur (only in some applications and not all the time).
2. How can I fix it?

Setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Gnome 3.28.1